# What's the symfony way to set a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, symfony1

```
<script type="text/javascript">var name="value";</script>
```

I need it to be executed before another file included by `use_javascript('name.js');`

How to do it in symfony?

Comment: What do you mean by "symfony style" ? Javascript is just Javascript, whether or not you are using any server-side framework.

Comment: @Pascal MARTIN ,just updated to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it any number of ways

let's say, in your action method, you add a template variable like so

```
$this->jsVar = 'foo';
```

Then, in your template file(s)

```
echo javascript_tag( 'var name="' . $jsVar . '";' );
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var name='<?php echo $jsVar; ?>';
</script>
```

### EDIT

Ok, based on your specific needs, you'll need to do a few things.  First, look at your page template (the one located in `apps/app-name/templates` - you should see a line that looks like this

```
<?php include_javascripts(); ?>
```

That's the function that takes all javascript resources defined in `view.yml` files or those included by the `use_javascript()` helper and prints them to the page.

So our goal, then, is to put a javascript block *in front of* where all the other scripts are included (and by in-front, I mean appearing first in source-order)

To solve this in a somewhat flexible manner, let's use a slot.  Modify the above line in your page template to look like this

```
<?php
  if ( has_slot( 'global_js_setup' ) )
  {
    include_slot( 'global_js_setup' );
  }
  include_javascripts();
?>
```

Then, in your action method

```
sfLoader::loadHelpers( 'Asset' );
$this->getResponse()->setSlot(
    'global_js_setup',
  , javascript_tag( 'var name="value";' );
);
```

You could extend this idea by using component slots if you wanted to.

Comment: I need it to be executed before another file included by `use_javascript('name.js');`

Comment: Ah, I see what you're getting at.  I'll update my answer in a sec

Answer (score 1):

To implement this in unobstrusive manner I'd recommend to use `use_dynamic_javascript` helper.

Comment: How to enforce it to appear before other javascript files are included?

Comment: Second parameter of `use_javascript` (and `use_dynamic_javascript` as well) helper is "`position`". As we can see from `sfWebResponse::$position`, valid positions are "`first`", "" (empty string) and "`last`" (instead we can use `sfWebResponse::FIRST`, `sfWebResponse::MIDDLE` or `sfWebResponse::LAST`).  

So, to enforce them appear before other files, you have to put them into "first" "slot" while others are put to "middle", or into "middle" while others are put "last" one.

Comment: Of course it's more convenient, but it makes much easier to "shoot your own leg" with it.

Answer (score 1):

this is twig excample you may use php.

```
{% if value %}
    <script type="text/javascript">var name="{{ value }}";</script>
{% endif %}
```

if your script won't work most of the mistakes are ( value is defined after adding main script), or ( you may var same variable in the main script it would bug your source. )

and if you need paste many variables you may use for. like this

```
{% if js_items %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
    {% for item in js_items %}
          var {{ item.name }} = "{{ item.value }}";
    {% endfor %}
    </script>
{% endif %}
```